# How do I separate Angular JS files and auto include them?

Tags: angularjs

How do I separate AngularJS controllers/services/routes by section of my app?
For example, I have sections such as:

- Settings
- Purchases
- Sales
- etc

I want to put all controllers/services etc into separate JS files, but don't want to have to have a long list of includes in my index.html.

Comment: maybe this helps you [angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure)

Comment: you can use lazyload in your router to call each controller and service related to your current route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we do in our projects, is we use a build process that concatenates all `.js` and `.css` files into 2 big minified files and we include them inside `index.html` . we name them something like `app-all.min.js` and `style-all.min.css`.

There are quite a lot of tools that do file concatenation, we use maven plugin for that but you can use a [grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) or a [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) task if maven isn't your thing.

Then you define which sub-directories in your project you want to concat and which to ignore. so your your file/directory layout isn't really an issue.

As for app structure, there are some very opinionated discussions out there about how you should do this. I found John Papa's angular style guide [section about application structure](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#application-structure-lift-principle) the most definite and widely used

Comment: Thanks for that. Ended up using Gulp with Laravel and working a treat.